# Devexpress ListBoxControl Add Item with multiple Colors

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I am looking for a solution to add an `Item` in a `ListBoxControl` with different colors in the same `Row`
ex: 'imported company [ XCompany ]' - i need 'imported company' with a gray color and the rest with black
also i need in case I have errors (Red)

I can't find (if exists) the method to add an `Html` text

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can activate the [HTML Text Formatting](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument4874) feature within the ListBoxControl via the [ListBoxControl.AllowHtmlDraw](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsBaseListBoxControl_AllowHtmlDrawtopic) property:

```
listBoxControl.AllowHtmlDraw = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True;
listBoxControl.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
    "Color <color=Red>Red</color>",
    "Color <color=Green>Green</color>",
    "Color <color=Blue>Blue</color>"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do that is implementing the `DrawItem` event of the `ListBox` with a method like :

```
    internal static void DrawListBox(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.ListBoxDrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cache.DrawString(e.Item.ToString(), e.Appearance.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.White),
            e.Bounds, e.Appearance.GetStringFormat());
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

In this case, all items are drawn in `Color.White`.

Of course, you can test your values via the properties contained in the `ListBoxDrawItemEventArgs`.

Comment: and how can I have two colors in List (one for info , and one for errors) ?

Comment: What I do is that I put in the items "Warning", "Info" and "Error" at the beginning and then something like `if (e.Item.ToString().BeginsWith("Info")) {//Coloring} e.Item.ToString().Remove(0,4)`.

Hope that helps !

Comment: It's OK , didn't test it , but DmitryG 's response is better , you can create the line as you like , choose Color, Font Size and more .. anyway , thanks and +1